# Filter out duplicate data in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-filter

How can I filter out duplicate tags in a list, so that only one of each tag is listed?

Here's my component code:

```
  <template>
    <v-layout row wrap>

    <ul>
      <li v-for="post in sortByName(posts)" :key="post.key">
       <v-chip
         v-for="i in sortByName(post.tags)"
         :key="i.key"
         :color="`${i.color} lighten-3`"
         label
         small
       >
          <span class="pr-2">
            {{ i.text }}
          </span>
        </v-chip>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </v-layout>
  </template>

  <script>
    import { mapState } from 'vuex'
    const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js')

    export default {
      data: () => ({

      }),
      computed: {
        ...mapState(['posts'])
    },
    methods: {
      // function to put the tags in the right order to a -> z
      sortByName (list) {
        return _.orderBy(list, 'text', 'asc');
      }
     }
    }
  </script>
```

For example, in the screenshot below, I want to filter out `Beach`, so that I only see `Beach` once in the list:

[image: screenshot]

The data looks like this:
[image: data format]

Comment: Just filter and order the list according to your requirements in a computed variable where you access the original data. The returned value of the computed statement is then the list you want to display. In the template, you then iterate over this computed variable.

Comment: yes okay, and how does that look like?

Comment: how does your data look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) that returns a new list (e.g., `filteredPosts`) of `posts` with its `tags` array filtered. In the example below, a  cache inside the computed property is used to track tags. The computed handler [`map`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `this.posts[]` into a new `Array` and [`filter`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) each entry's `tags[]`, tracking new tags in the cache as "seen" and removing tags already "seen".

*template:*

```
<li v-for="post in filteredPosts" :key="post.key">
```

*script:*

```js
computed: {
  filteredPosts() {
    const tagCache = {};
    const newPosts = this.posts.map(post => {
      return {
        ...post,
        tags: post.tags.filter(tag => {
          const seen = tagCache[tag.text];
          tagCache[tag.text] = true;
          return !seen;
        })
      };
    });
    return newPosts;
  }
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [
        {
          key: 1,
          tags: [
            { color: 'blue', text: 'Sky' },
            { color: 'green', text: 'Tree' },
            { color: 'yellow', text: 'Beach' },
          ],
        },
        {
          key: 2,
          tags: [
            { color: 'purple', text: 'Grape' },
            { color: 'red', text: 'Apple' },
            { color: 'orange', text: 'Orange' },
          ],
        },
        {
          key: 3,
          tags: [
            { color: 'blue', text: 'Blueberry' },
            { color: 'yellow', text: 'Beach' },
          ],
        },
        {
          key: 4,
          tags: [
            { color: 'pink', text: 'Flower' },
            { color: 'yellow', text: 'Beach' },
          ],
        },
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // function to put the tags in the right order to a -> z
    sortByName (list) {
      return _.orderBy(list, 'text', 'asc');
    },
  },
  computed: {
    filteredPosts () {
      const tagCache = {};
      // map `posts` to a new array that filters
      // out duplicate tags
      const newPosts = this.posts.map(post => {
          return {
            ...post,
            tags: post.tags.filter(tag => {
              const seen = tagCache[tag.text];
              tagCache[tag.text] = true;
              return !seen;
            })
          };
        });
      return newPosts;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
@import 'https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.1.9/dist/vuetify.min.css'
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.1.9/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid class="pa-0">
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="post in filteredPosts" :key="post.key">
            <v-chip v-for="i in sortByName(post.tags)"
                    :key="i.key"
                    :color="`${i.color} lighten-3`"
                    label
                    small>
              <span class="pr-2">
                {{ i.text }}
              </span>
            </v-chip>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: @Lukas No problem :)